# Selecting column and apply formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I want to update format of cnic column in a sheet and it can be placed at any location. I have written below code but facing error. Can anyone check and rectify below code please.

```
Sub CNIC_ExternalAccountNumber()

Dim CNIC As String
Dim x As Integer
'Dim externalAccountNumber As String

CNIC = "CNIC"

For x = 1 To 10
  If Cells(1, x).Value = CNIC Then
    Columns(x & ":" & x).Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0000000000000"
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `Columns(x).NumberFormat = "0000000000000"`  What is the error you're getting?

Comment: error is at below line. actually I need to select the column where it found heading CNIC.                                                                                                               
  Columns(x & ":" & x).Select

Comment: You don't need to select anything to set the format, and `Columns(x)` is correct

Comment: Try `Cells(1, x).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "0000000000000"`

Comment: What "error is at below line" does mean?

Comment: FaneDuru your answer is also usefull. Cells(1, x).EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "0000000000000"              Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the number "CNIC" is. However, I'm able to run the code by placing the dimmed variables on a separate line.

```
Sub CNIC_ExternalAccountNumber()
    Dim CNIC As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim externalAccountNumber As String

    CNIC = 1000

    For x = 1 To 10
        If Cells(1, x).Value = CNIC Then
            Cells(1, x).Select

            Selection.NumberFormat = "0000000000000"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Need to update column's formatting not the cell's formatting where CNIC is written on heading

Answer (score 0):

Sub CNIC_ExternalAccountNumber()

Dim CNIC As String
Dim x As Integer
Dim externalAccountNumber As String

CNIC = "CNIC"

For x = 1 To 10

If Cells(1, x).Value = CNIC Then

Columns(x).Select

Selection.NumberFormat = "0000000000000"

End If

Next

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CNIC_ExternalAccountNumber()

    Dim CNIC As String
    Dim x As Integer
    'Dim externalAccountNumber As String
    
    CNIC = "CNIC"
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
        For x = 1 To 10
      
          If .Cells(1, x).Value = CNIC Then
            .Columns(x).NumberFormat = "0000000000000"
          End If
          
        Next
        
    End With

End Sub
```